# JavaScript regular expression with word boundary requirement

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a regex for a phone number that is part of a larger string and I'm having a bit of trouble with one particular requirement.

The basic requirements are to match on the following phone number styles - standard australian phone numbers with an area code or the international prefix and a little leeway for spaces and hyphens:

```
0395551234
03 9555 1234
03-9555-1234
+61395551234
```

However, I only want to match a number if it has a word boundary before the first character and after the last character, so the following styles should not match:

```
0395551234word
03 9555 1234word
03-9555-1234word
+61395551234word
word0395551234
word03 9555 1234
word03-9555-1234
word+61395551234
```

This is my regex string:

```
((\+61[ \-]?[2378]|\b0[2378]|\(0[2378]\))[ \-]?[0-9]{4}[ \-]?[0-9]{4}\b)
```

but it's not correct because it will still match on:

```
word+61395551234
```

I can't use the word boundary `\b` before the `+` character because the `+` character is not a word character. I will also note that I'm using JavaScript so  I can't use the positive look behind construct to only match the `+` character if it's at the start of the line or preceded by a space character. If I could use that, here is a Perl regular expression that would achieve my requirement:

```
(((?<=^|\s)\+61[ \-]?[2378]|\b0[2378]|\(0[2378]\))[ \-]?[0-9]{4}[ \-]?[0-9]{4}\b)
```

I also can't do any extra processing on the large string that I'm working with, because I need to retain its structure exactly, so no `replace()` operations before trying the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `\b` before `+` character as that is not considered a word character. Instead use: `(?:^|\s)` before `+` to make sure `+` comes at line start or after a whitespace.

Use this regex:

```
(((?:^|\s)\+61[ -]?[2378]|\b0[2378]|\(0[2378]\))[ -]?[0-9]{4}[ -]?[0-9]{4}\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX4uG0/1)

Comment: A non-capturing group, I see. This is almost perfect, however I notice that if the string is "word +61395551234", then I capture " +61395551234" - note the extra space at the start? But I can't explain why it's captured.

Comment: [Do you want this](https://regex101.com/r/aX4uG0/2) Remember that preceding will still be matched (not captured) as there is no lookbehind in JS.

Comment: That is slightly better. Thanks for your help here, this is probably close enough for me to work with. :)